# Unable to get multiple response requests on aiohttp

Tags: asynchronous, python-requests, parallel-processing, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I am trying to pull multiple responses requests using aiohttp but I am getting an attribute error.

My code looks like this, I had to obscure it because I am using a private api.

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio

async def get_data(session, x):
    try:
        async with session.get(url=f'https://api.abc.com/{x}') as response:
            data = await response.json()
            return data.json()
    except Exception as e:
        print("Unable to get url {} due to {}.".format(ticker, e.__class__))

async def main(datas):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        ret = await asyncio.gather(*[get_data(data, session) for data in datas])
        return ret

datas = ['x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4'] 
resukts = asyncio.run(main(datas))
```

My error looks like this,

```
Unable to get url <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x1013f6ee0> due to <class 'AttributeError'>.
Unable to get url <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x1013f6ee0> due to <class 'AttributeError'>.
Unable to get url <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x1013f6ee0> due to <class 'AttributeError'>.
Unable to get url <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x1013f6ee0> due to <class 'AttributeError'>.
```

What am I doing wrong?

I was expecting to get the response from the api in parallel or asynchronously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

response.json() already returns the parsed JSON data, so calling .json() on data again is unnecessary and will raise an AttributeError.

Try like this

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio

async def get_data(session, x):
    try:
        async with session.get(url=f'https://api.abc.com/{x}') as response:
            data = await response.json()
            return data  # Return the parsed JSON data directly, no need for .json()
    except Exception as e:
        print("Unable to get url {} due to {}.".format(x, e.__class__))

async def main(datas):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        ret = await asyncio.gather(*[get_data(session, data) for data in datas])  # Pass session and data in the correct order
        return ret

datas = ['x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4'] 
results = asyncio.run(main(datas))  # Correct the variable name to "results"
```

The OP is asking for a way to return the result in a dict format:
this is how you can do it :

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio

async def get_data(session, x):
    try:
        async with session.get(url=f'https://api.abc.com/{x}') as response:
            data = await response.json()
            return data
    except Exception as e:
        print("Unable to get url {} due to {}.".format(x, e.__class__))
        return None

async def main(datas):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        ret = await asyncio.gather(*[get_data(session, data) for data in datas])
        return {datas[i]: ret[i] for i in range(len(datas))}  # Return the results as a dictionary

datas = ['x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4']
results = asyncio.run(main(datas))
```

Comment: how do i add headers?

Comment: What do you mean by headers @anarchy?

Comment: nevermind i got it thanks, will mark yours correct after the timer

Comment: Happy I solved your issue

Comment: is there a way to return the results in a dict? for example. results[x1] = datasx1 etc

Comment: Edited with solution to get result in a dict format

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254660/discussion-between-anarchy-and-nadir-belhaj).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76766188/how-to-add-a-try-until-success-loop-inside-aiohttp-requests i have another question which is an extension of this one if you have time to look at it. thanks!