# How to add a try until success loop inside aiohttp requests

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-requests, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I have the following code,

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio

async def get_data(session, x):
    try:
        async with session.get(url=f'https://api.abc.com/{x}') as response:
            data = await response
            if data.status_code == 200:
                data = float(data.json())
                return data
            else:
                continue
    except Exception as e:
        print("Unable to get url {} due to {}.".format(x, e.__class__))
        return None

async def main(datas):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        ret = await asyncio.gather(*[get_data(session, data) for data in datas])
        return {datas[i]: ret[i] for i in range(len(datas))}  # Return the results as a dictionary

datas = ['x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4']
results = asyncio.run(main(datas))
```

I want to query the api until i get a response == 200 and i am able to get float(data), if the data is text, it will fail. so it should try the float(data) until it succeeds.

If either fail, I want to retry until it succeeds.

Will the code work? I am not used to asych code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio

async def get_data(session, x):
    while True:
        try:
            async with session.get(url=f'https://api.abc.com/{x}') as response:
                if response.status == 200:
                    data = await response.json()
                    try:
                        data = float(data)
                        return data
                    except ValueError:
                        print("Data is not a valid float. Retrying...")
                else:
                    print("Received non-200 status code. Retrying...")
            await asyncio.sleep(1)  # Wait for 1 second before retrying
        except Exception as e:
            print("Unable to get url {} due to {}. Retrying...".format(x, e.__class__))
            await asyncio.sleep(1)  # Wait for 1 second before retrying

async def main(datas):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        ret = await asyncio.gather(*[get_data(session, data) for data in datas])
        return {datas[i]: ret[i] for i in range(len(datas))}  # Return the results as a dictionary

datas = ['x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4']
results = asyncio.run(main(datas))
```

In the updated get_data function, we have a while True loop that will keep retrying until the conditions are met. When the API response has a status code of 200, we attempt to convert the data to a float using float(data). If it succeeds, we return the result. If the data is not a valid float (raises a ValueError), we print a message and retry.

Comment: shouldnt the await response be before the status check or something?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one to check if the response is 200:

```
if response.status == 200:
```

Comment: okay, but where would that fit in the code, is the rest of it correct?

Comment: I have another question as well if you can take a look at it, thanks! 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76781109/converting-aiohttp-script-to-asyncio-requests-aiohttp-not-working-on-ubuntu-w

Comment: I checked your other question and answered @anarchy