# Converting aiohttp script to asyncio + requests (aiohttp not working on ubuntu while asyncio + requests works)

Tags: python, python-requests, python-asyncio, aiohttp, code-conversion

I am using the following script to do queries on a website.

It works on macos, however it does not work with ubuntu. I have tried requests and it works, I also tried a simple asyncio + requests with the website and it works.

I need help converting it to using requests instead of aiohttp. Any help would be appreciated.

This is my original code.

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio

async def get_data(session, x):
    while True:
        try:
            async with session.get(url=f'https://api.abc.com/{x}') as response:
                if response.status == 200:
                    data = await response.json()
                    try:
                        data = float(data)
                        return data
                    except ValueError:
                        print("Data is not a valid float. Retrying...")
                else:
                    print("Received non-200 status code. Retrying...")
            await asyncio.sleep(1)  # Wait for 1 second before retrying
        except Exception as e:
            print("Unable to get url {} due to {}. Retrying...".format(x, e.__class__))
            await asyncio.sleep(1)  # Wait for 1 second before retrying

async def main(datas):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        ret = await asyncio.gather(*[get_data(session, data) for data in datas])
        return {datas[i]: ret[i] for i in range(len(datas))}  # Return the results as a dictionary

datas = ['x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4']
results = asyncio.run(main(datas))
```

Here is my code

```
import asyncio
import requests

async def get_data(x):
    while True:
        try:
            response = requests.get(url=f'https://api.abc.com/{x}')
            if response.status_code == 200:
                try:
                    data = float(response.json())
                    return data
                except ValueError:
                    print("Data is not a valid float. Retrying...")
            else:
                print("Received non-200 status code. Retrying...")
            await asyncio.sleep(1)  # Wait for 1 second before retrying
        except Exception as e:
            print("Unable to get url {} due to {}. Retrying...".format(x, e.__class__))
            await asyncio.sleep(1)  # Wait for 1 second before retrying

async def main(datas):
    tasks = [get_data(data) for data in datas]
    ret = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    return {datas[i]: ret[i] for i in range(len(datas))}  # Return the results as a dictionary

datas = ['x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4']
results = asyncio.run(main(datas))
print(results)
```

and the error I am getting so far,

```
Unable to get data for x1 due to <class 'TypeError'>. Retrying...
Unable to get data for x2 due to <class 'TypeError'>. Retrying...
Unable to get data for x3 due to <class 'TypeError'>. Retrying...
Unable to get data for x4 due to <class 'TypeError'>. Retrying...
Unable to get data for x1 due to <class 'TypeError'>. Retrying...
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Most likely Ubuntu doesn't work because of certificate problems.

`certifi` package can be used for providing fresh client certificates (please don't forget to keep the latest version of `certifi` in your setup).

Tuning `aiohttp` to use `certifi` instead of system storage is relatively simple:

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import certifi
import ssl

async def get_data(session, x):
    while True:
        try:
            ssl_context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS)
            ssl_context.load_verify_locations(capath=certifi.where())
            async with session.get(
                url=f'https://api.abc.com/{x}',
                connector=aiohttp.TCPConnector(ssl=ssl_context),
            ) as response:
                if response.status == 200:
                    data = await response.json()
                    try:
                        data = float(data)
                        return data
                    except ValueError:
                        print("Data is not a valid float. Retrying...")
                else:
                    print("Received non-200 status code. Retrying...")
            await asyncio.sleep(1)  # Wait for 1 second before retrying
        except Exception as e:
            print("Unable to get url {} due to {}. Retrying...".format(x, e.__class__))
            await asyncio.sleep(1)  # Wait for 1 second before retrying

async def main(datas):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        ret = await asyncio.gather(*[get_data(session, data) for data in datas])
        return {datas[i]: ret[i] for i in range(len(datas))}  # Return the results as a dictionary

datas = ['x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4']
results = asyncio.run(main(datas))
```

Answer (score 1):

By catching the ValueError and printing a message, the function should not raise any more errors related to parsing JSON data

```
async def get_data(x):
    while True:
        try:
            response = requests.get(url=f'https://api.abc.com/{x}')
            if response.status_code == 200:
                try:
                    data = float(response.json())
                    return data
                except ValueError:
                    print("Data is not a valid float. Retrying...")
            else:
                print(f"Received non-200 status code ({response.status_code}). Retrying...")
            await asyncio.sleep(1)  # Wait for 1 second before retrying
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Unable to get data for {x} due to {type(e).__name__}. Retrying...")
            await asyncio.sleep(1)  # Wait for 1 second before retrying
```